# Java Stream sum() short circuiting

Tags: java, java-stream

While doing a project I wrote this line, basically it decided whether or not to merge the current node based on how many children there are.

```
int succNodes = Arrays.stream(children).mapToInt(PRQuadNode::count).sum();
if (succNodes <= bucketingParam) { /* do something */ }
```

The problem is that `succNodes` will often be significantly larger than `bucketingParam`. And there's no point to continue counting if I have already found a large enough sum. What would be the best way to enable the stream to stop  early, if I knew I was going to fail the check succNodes <= bucketingParam?

Note: In  this case children is always of size 4.

Note 2: PRQuadNode::count is a recursive method, it is not tail recursive.

Comment: Per SO policy you Can ask homework questions, if you have made a good faith effort to solve it and your school does not have a policy against posting this. So you should be fine posting what you have (FYI).

Comment: You're actually better off doing this without a stream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, Java 9 comes with the `takeWhile` method, which is a short-circuiting operation of the stream, returning *the longest prefix of elements matching the given predicate*.

Because the predicate depends on the sum of the previous elements, a wrapper has to be used in order to store the intermediate result. In the example below, I use the `AtomicInteger` class:

```
AtomicInteger sum = new AtomicInteger();
Arrays.asList(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17).stream()
    .takeWhile(i -> sum.addAndGet(i) < 15)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Returns:

```
2
3
5
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot short-circuit the stream pipeline with the use of streams alone.

one workaround (with the use of side-effects) would be:

```
int[] c = new int[1];
boolean r = Arrays.stream(children).noneMatch(e -> (c[0] = c[0] + e.count()) > bucketingParam);
if (r) { /* do something */ }
```

This accomplishes the task but unfortunately, is not threadsafe (doubt you're ever going to run this in parallel anyway as your source will always have 4 elements).

An imperative approach would be:

```
int succNodes = 0;
boolean result = true;
for (PRQuadNode p : children) {
    if (succNodes > bucketingParam) {
         result = false;
         break;
    }
    succNodes += p.count();
}

if (result) { /* do something */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

One cannot do this with `stream`. However, you can already filter out if it is greater than `bucketingParam`.
If any of them already greater than `bucketingParam` there's no point in continuing.

```
if (Arrays.stream(children).mapToInt(PRQuadNode::count)
                           .noneMatch(x -> x > bucketingParam)) {
    int succNodes = Arrays.stream(children).mapToInt(PRQuadNode::count).sum();
}
```